# Beforeunload Function is Not working And not updating the records after unload

Tags: php, ajax, onbeforeunload, onunload

**Here is my code**

```
function myfoo() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "update.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    data: {
      Eventid: 1,
      Seats: 'Seats'
    },
    success: function(r) {}
  });
}

$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
  return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
});
$(window).on('unload', function() {
  console.log('calling ajax');
  myfoo();
});
```

**update.php code**

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'conn.php';

if(isset($_SESSION['Seats'])) {
    $seatS=$_SESSION['Seats'];
    $Eventid=$_SESSION['Eventid'];
    $cats = explode(" ", $seatS);
    $cats = preg_split('/,/', $seatS, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    foreach($cats as $key => $cat ) {
        $cat  = mysql_real_escape_string($cats[$key]);
        $cat = trim($cat);
        if($cat !=NULL) {
            $stmt = $con->prepare('UPDATE fistevent SET `Status`=" " where `Event_Id`=? AND `seats`="'.$cat.'" AND `Status`="Hold" ');
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $_SESSION['Eventid']);
            $stmt->execute();
            session_destroy();
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: @Barmar sir iam trying to update records with window unload .but records not updating after unload

Comment: Put that in the question, not a comment.

Comment: Are you being prompted when you try to leave the page?

Comment: Yes i got the message before leaving the window

Comment: this code working fine on localhost and updating records after unload .but on live site it is not updating records after showing prompted message

Comment: Check the network tab to see if it's sending the AJAX request. BTW, synchronous AJAX is deprecated, you shouldn't use `async: false`.

Comment: can i send a session variables in  data: {Eventid: 1,Seats:'Seats'}, ?

Comment: No, session variables are internal to PHP. Those parameters become `$_POST['Eventid']` and `$_POST['Seats']`

Comment: Okay sir..i use them as session variables in update.php ..could you please check my update.php file above. is that the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AJAX `data:` parameters are put in `$_POST`, not `$_SESSION`.

You can't use `mysql_real_escape_string` if you're using `mysqli`. You don't need to escape parameters when you're using `bind_param()`. And you can use `explode()` instead of `preg_split()`, since there's no regular expression pattern in your delimiter; `array_filter()` can be used to remove blank entries.

```
<?php
include 'conn.php';

if(isset($_POST['Seats'])) {
    $seatS=$_POST['Seats'];
    $_SESSION['Seats'] = $seatS;
    $Eventid=$_POST['Eventid'];
    $_SESSION['Eventid'] = $Eventid;
    $cats = array_filter(array_map('trim', explode(',', $seatS)));
    $stmt = $con->prepare('UPDATE fistevent SET `Status`=" " where `Event_Id`=? AND `seats`= ? AND `Status`="Hold" ') or die($con->error);
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['Eventid'], $cat);
    foreach($cats as $key => $cat ) {
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: sir there is no errors but it does not updating the records

Comment: Can you execute the query by hand? `UPDATE fistevent SET Status = " " WHERE Event_Id = 1 AND seats = "Seats" AND Status = "Hold"`

Comment: i think the problem is passing the wrong data .i have to send this data in ajax $seatS=$_SESSION['Seats'];
    $Eventid=$_SESSION['Eventid'];.. hows it possible?

Comment: You can't set session variables in Javascript. It can only send `$_POST` and `$_GET` variables. You can set the session variables from the post parameters if you want, but I don't see why that's needed for this query.

Comment: or this field data >> <input type="hidden" name="Eventid" id="Eventid" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['Eventid'])){$Eventid =$_POST['Eventid']; echo $Eventid; } ?>" />
     <input type="hidden" name="finalSeats" id="finalSeats" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['finalSeats'])){$FinalSeats =$_POST['finalSeats']; echo $FinalSeats; } ?>" />

Comment: i have to send these input fields data in data: {Eventid: 1,Seats:'Seats'}, so that i can get selected Eventid and selected seats on update.php

Comment: `{ EventId: $("#Eventid").val(), Seats: $("#finalSeats").val() }`

Comment: still not updating the records

Comment: thanks sir .there is miner mistake in code that we are using Eventid but in data post name is EventID

Comment: @krish So the problem turned out to be just a typo?